# GSON treats integer as double

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I need to read integer and double as is in String property but GSON treats every int as double (yep, i understand that it is JSON standard).

So for example I have class:

```
public class MyObject {
    String value;
}
```

In some case i've got this JSON - `{"value": 1}` and sometimes - `{"value": 2.4}`.

And i have to display this values as they are, but first value will be read as `1.0`.

I've tried to use `JsonDeserializer` and `TypeAdapter`, both have method like `getAsString` and both of them firstly convert value to double and then return it.

How method looks in `JsonPrimitive`:

```
@Override
public String getAsString() {
    if (isNumber()) {
        return getAsNumber().toString();
    } else if (isBoolean()) {
        return getAsBooleanWrapper().toString();
    } else {
        return (String) value;
    }
}
```

You can see `isNumber` check here.

So is it possilbe to solve this problem somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class youClass(){
  private int i;
}
```

and then :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
yourClass = gson.fromJson(jsonText , yourClass);
yourClass.getI();
```

hope to be usefull

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is you can get the value as **String** from your **JSON**

And create **check** to know the value is **double** or just an **integer** , using below a tricky way.

Try below code:

```
   String stringArr[] = {"1", "1.0",  "1.2", "3.5", "2.5"};
        for(int i=0;i<stringArr.length;i++){
              if(stringArr[i].equals(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(stringArr[i])))){
                    System.out.println("It's a double value : "+stringArr[i]);
              }else{
                    System.out.println("It's a inte value : "+stringArr[i]);
              }
        }
```

**Output:**

> It's a inte value : 1
>
> It's a double value : 1.0
>
> It's a double value : 1.2
>
> It's a double value : 3.5
>
> It's a double value : 2.5

Comment: I need to display trailing zeros if it comes from server-side. If it comes without zeros I need to display without zeros. That's why I said I wanted to leave values as they came from server.

Comment: @Google i misunderstood the problem, i just updated above one

Comment: But problem here that I can't get "1", not "1.0" when using Gson. Gson automatically converts "1" to "1.0"